# Android content provider and sqlite database

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider

I'm working on two applications that will share the same data.  The obvious solution is to use a content provider.  What I'm not clear on is the deployment.

My initial thoughts are that the content provider will be developed as a library and included in each of the apps.  I know there are problems with this;

- The content provider would be deployed twice and have the same authority.  In know the authority could be changed but then you effectively have two content providers.
- Sqlite uses the context to determine where the data is stored.  So in which app is the data stored?  If I delete the app the data will go with it.  I imagined it would have some central store but this doesn't appear to be the case.
- Over time the content provider may be updated.  We could end up with a situation with an updated app using the older content provider.

An alternative to that is to deploy the content provider in one of the apps or in its own app but that then causes a dependency.  The apps would have to have the content provider app installed.  Not a great user experience.

What is the best strategy for this?  Content providers seems to be the right way forward but leaves me with a lot of questions.